# Failed to resolve: com.github.smrtyvz:ArchedImageProgressBar:2.01

Tags: java, android

I hope you are fine.
I have problem in android studio, hours and hours I'm trying to implement library of Loading Button or image circular progress ( such as telegram progress ), and this library one of theme, when I try to implement in android studio I get this error message:

> Failed to resolve: com.github.smrtyvz:ArchedImageProgressBar:2.01

any solution or suggestion ?

this is my root build.Gradle

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
            maven {url "https://maven.springframework.org/release"}
            maven { url "https://maven.restlet.com" }
                google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
}

allprojects {
        repositories {
                google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 28
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "blocks.youtube.hichem.soft"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.2'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.2'
        implementation 'com.github.smrtyvz:ArchedImageProgressBar:2.01'
            }
```

the Link of Library in github ;

https://github.com/smrtyvz/ArchedImageProgressBar

whats wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add this in your root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Brother, right i just added { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in the second one

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

in the root of your Gradle build file (outside of the `buildscript` tag).